# Expand the main div element when the inner div tags expands

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on a classical asp.net mvc application. I use the `_Layout` page and all the CSS that comes with it. The CSS for the main div is :

```
#main {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}
```

I created a view which looks like this :

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="drawForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDocument", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table border="1" id="drawDocument">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 40%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
        </colgroup>
        @Html.Partial("_PartialHeader", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialDrawing", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialBody", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialFooter", Model)

    </table>
    if (ViewBag.Status == 1)
    {
        <button type="submit" id="submitDocument">Запази</button> 
        <button style="float:right;" id="finalizeDocument">Приключи</button>  
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index")
    }
}
</div>
<div id="imageGallery"></div>
</div>
```

The whole idea is to position the `imageGallery` next to the `drawForm` that's why I created and the `mainContainer` div because I find an example that had this structure. However using this structure if my table's height become over a certain size the `main` div stops to expand and the table gets outside the borders of the main div, before that the main div was expanding as much as the table needed, no matter how big is the table. This is the CSS for my view :

```
#mainContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 950px;

    }
#drawForm 
{
    min-width: 690px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 800px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#imageGallery {
    width: 100px; 
    height: 700px;
    float: right; 
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    }
#drawDocument {
    /*border-collapse: collapse;
    result in strange behaviour in Firefox*/
    border-spacing: 0px;
    min-width: 690px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

now I have the tow div tags on the same level but got the problem described above. How can I change the CSS so the `main` div tag starts to change it's size according to the size of the table?

Comment: Template code isn't useful for debugging CSS problems, we need generated HTML.

Comment: Why does the div need to be floating and inline? Do you have a compelling reason?

Comment: @Mr Lister No, I just want two divs displayed next to each other. The implementation is what follows. This is what I found on the web and really worked but cause this problem.